# How do I convert a double slashed path to a path that open() accepts?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, path, filepath

I have a raw string representing a path on windows like this: `'F:\\Music\\v flac\\1-06 No Quarter.flac\r'` What should I do to it so that open() accepts it? os.path.normpath() isn't working.

```
>>> path
'F:\\Music\\v flac\\1-06 No Quarter.flac\r'
>>> fp=open(path,'rb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'F:\\Music\\v flac\\1-06 No
 Quarter.flac\r'
>>> fp=open(os.path.normpath(path),'rb')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'F:\\Music\\v flac\\1-06 No
 Quarter.flac\r'
>>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The double slashes are *not* the problem here. It is the `\r` carriage return character at the end that is causing you problems.

String it from the path:

```
fp = open(path.strip(), 'rb')
```

Python is merely showing a string literal representation of your `path` string, for ease of debugging. Any character with special meaning, outside of the printable ASCII range, is escaped, including backslashes. The value *itself* does not have doubled backslashes:

```
>>> path = 'F:\\Music\\v flac\\1-06 No Quarter.flac\r'
>>> path
'F:\\Music\\v flac\\1-06 No Quarter.flac\r'
>>> print path
F:\Music\v flac\1-06 No Quarter.flac
>>> path[:3]
'F:\\'
>>> len(path[:3])
3
```

Note how *printing* `path` shows the path value having only single backslashes and how the first 3 characters of the path are `F:\`, the string having length 3 and not 4. In a Python string literal the backslashes would denote escape sequences however, so Python escapes those too.